# How do I make my injected javascript code appear when theres a final Completer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi Im new to flutter and this is the only remaining problem I have for my very first app to be finished, for some reason the injected javascript I used is not appearing in the WebView app.

> **FIXED** (sorry for the delayed edit: the code was (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';")
>
> Note: Im using the webview_flutter by the flutter dev team and I want to have BOTH refresh FAB and injected code working at the same time

my code is below:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  WebViewController _myController;
      final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                  body: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://syncshop.online/en/',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
          onPageFinished: (controller) {
          _myController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
          },
          ),
    floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              controller.data.reload();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          );
          }
          return Container();
        }),
          ),
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think, `_myController` is not assigned anything. So, instead try using the `_controller` for `evaluateJavascript()`.

Like this: `(await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");`

Comment: I would suggest adding the answer code as answer, instead of editing the question itself. Do you Mind If I edit the question and post the answer?

Comment: Hi @KylaDC. If your doubts are resolved. Please, accept the Question edit and answer as well.

Comment: By the way, those are "questions" not "doubts".  "Doubt" implies disbelief, and is not normally needed for factually resolvable questions.

Comment: Hi sorry I wasnt able to reply faster. I jut got back online again. Yep Ill edit the answer now. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, `_myController` is not assigned anything.

So, Instead try using the `_controller` for `evaluateJavascript()`. Like this:

```dart
(await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
```